# java.sql.BatchUpdateException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.44] [Error 1338] [SQLState HY000] for a python etl code

Tags: python, teradata

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.44] [Error 1338] [SQLState HY000] for a python etl code .the code runs fine for a while but now i am getting the error on daily basis. Also it says Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException. How to enable that?

Comment: your Exception object in the except clause like except java.lang.SQLException, e: - should have a function e.getNextException() - implemented by the JDBC driver - which would give you additional info on the error. Also, if you can extract the exact SQL causing it, and run it in the SQL*Assistant directly - it will give an idea as well.

Comment: @access_granted Hi,Thanks for answering-How exactly should i implement getnext() exception there.Also do i need to import any library/module for that.i am new to python, the script runs fine in my system and through jupyter labs but failing in another system that too after running successfully for 1 or 2 weeks. Any idea  what could have changed.